# Is it possible to chain RewriteCond in htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am going to be doing some basic `%{HTTP_HOST}` work in my `.htaccess` file and was wondering if it would be possible to do something similar to this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ((foo|bar|baz).com)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/apps/%1/webroot%{REQUEST_URI}  -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/apps/%1/webroot%{REQUEST_URI}  -f
  RewriteRule %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/apps/%1/webroot%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?uri=$1 [QSA,L]
```

basically, if someone visits `foo.com` on any sub-domain, I want them to be served files directly from that folder but also have any requests that aren't for specific files sent to my `index.php` file for processing (which will do the routing)

The reason I am asking is because what I have written above does not actually work, so is there a way to do it? (also if this SHOULD work then it'll obviously be a problem with the rest of my `.htaccess` file, but it all works when dealing with just one application folder)

The other (messy IMO) way would be to route everything to the folders and have a second `.htaccess` file for each domain, but I'd rather not do this if it can be done in one file!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first rewrite rule is missing a regex, which makes the rewrite engine thing you are trying to match (as a regular expression) `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/apps/%1/webroot%{REQUEST_URI}` and you want to rewrite that to `[L]`. I suspect you want that to look like:

```
RewriteRule ^ /apps/%1/webroot%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

The `^` matches anything, since you've already vetted the request with your 3 conditions.

Now you need to add a few conditions to your last rule so that it doesn't blindly get applied to everything. You probably want something like:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?uri=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: schoolboy error! However, the first request should handle the file side of things, and if I was to allow it to access files in the root, it'd match my library folders and config files, so I'll leave that as is.